# Conditional formatting google sheets, match date between two dates- mark that row that is matching

Tags: date, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, match, conditional-formatting

I am looking for a way to match any date in a column of dates with a bunch of start/end periods at columns next to it. If any match, mark my cell.
I have managed to do this for one row, but I would like it to look at a whole column (or set range ex X6-X10) and compare with a bunch of date-periods in two columns.

Any one with any ideas of how I can do that?

This is what I have come up with so far:
[image]

And I am using this formula:
`=AND($X$6>=$R$6,$X$6<=$T$6)`

But, as I said, this only works for one row today. I would like to look through all rows in the columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This formula should work:

```
=COUNTIFS(X$6:X,">="&R6,X$6:X,"<="&T6)
```

[image]

Comment: what does the "&" in "&$X6" mean?

Comment: & just concatenates the condition with the cell reference. This is how countif(s) work

Comment: Hey man! It works like a charm! Thank you so much! Your a genius!! And thanks for all the time you've put in this! I would probably never come up with this solution my self..